# Stop further execution process if client cancels request in between in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating pdf of websites using puppeteer, cheerio and pdfkit on my NodeJs server which takes lot of time, now I wanted to abort all processes if client cancels request i.e closes browser, tab etc so that server doesn't process unnecessary processes.
For example:

```
app.get("/api/processScreenshot/:url", async (req, resp) => {
  const links = await collectAllLinks(url);
  const screenshotsPath = await takeScreenshots(links);
  const pdfPath = await createPDF(screenshotsPath);
  resp.status(200).end(pdfPath);
});
```

Is it possible to abort all the further processes inside this rest API if request gets cancel by any means i.e it receives **cancel**, **close** or **abort** event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *general* way to cancel *any* asynchronous function, so if you just see an `await` you will need to dive into the function to see if they have some facility to cancel the process.

For example, why is `createPdf` asynchronous? Maybe it calls an external process? You could kill that process. Maybe it calls a 3rd party API? Cancel HTTP request.

A good example of a promise-based API that can be cancelled is fetch, which uses `AbortController`. This is a good pattern to apply to your own functions too, but you need to explicitly (mostly manually) write code for this for any function you want to add cancel support to.

Comment: what if these are some synchronous calls, let say some heavy computations, I know most of the promise based APIs provides abort or kill events but what if someone intentionally make call and then cancels the request in between, and the request was doing some computation stuffs, this would make my server busy for actual users/use cases.

Comment: @SandeepRathi you can't really interupt a synchronous function. For *something else* to interupt it, it must be asynchronous. As long as a synchronous function runs in Javascript, no other javascript code executes until it's done.

Comment: Unless it runs in a separate process altogether, or a webworker.